# Primary Key Unique Constraint confusion / solution

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a database with Employees, a Skill table and a Skillset table:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
    EmployeeID NUMBER (5, 0) NOT NULL,
    *.....other fields*
CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_PK PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeID));


CREATE TABLE SKILL(
SkillID NUMBER (5, 0) NOT NULL,
Description VARCHAR2(30),
CONSTRAINT SKILL_PK PRIMARY KEY (SkillID),
CONSTRAINT SKILL_FK FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EmployeeID));

CREATE TABLE SKILLSET(
    SkillSetID NUMBER (5,0) NOT NULL,
    EmployeeID NUMBER (5,0) NOT NULL,
    SkillID NUMBER (5,0) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT SKILLSET_PK PRIMARY KEY (SkillSetID)
CONSTRAINT SKILLSET_SKILL_FK FOREIGN KEY (SkillID) REFERENCES Skill(SkillID));
CONSTRAINT SKILLSET_EMP_FK FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EmployeeID));
```

I have employees that can have multiple skills, and this is stored on the skillset table.
I am getting ORA-00001: unique constraint (YSKILLSETID) violated when I attempt to assign more than one employee a skill from the Skill table.

This makes sense to me, and I'm still looking for a solution to allow multiple employees to have mutliple skills.

However, my confusion arises in that one employee can have many skills, shouldnt that be bound by the unique constraint to?

```
INSERT INTO SKILLSET VALUES (125, 31150, 2513);
INSERT INTO SKILLSET VALUES (124, 31150, 2523);
INSERT INTO SKILLSET VALUES (122, 31150, 8493);
INSERT INTO SKILLSET VALUES (121, 31153, 2141);
INSERT INTO SKILLSET VALUES (120, 31154, 2521);
INSERT INTO SKILLSET VALUES (119, 31154, 2141);
INSERT INTO SKILLSET VALUES (118, 31150, 2521);
```

[screenshot of test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OB6w2.png)

My questions:

- What can I do to have many employees connect to multiple skills?
- Why does this work for one employees having many skills?

Comment: The model itself is quite strange: you have an employee as attribute of a skill and try to create another table with some additional column that represents the same relationship. `EmployeeID` should be removed from `skill` table. The statement you've provided will not return this error, because there's no repetitive `SkillSetID` values

Comment: I've edited the Skill table, that was a mistake, it shouldn't have employee ID.

Comment: The only unique constraint on SKILLSET is `SKILLSET_PK PRIMARY KEY (SkillSetID)` and all SkillSetIDs are unique, so I can't see you got that error. What is YSKILLSETID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would help to phrase the problem domain clearly. I think:

The system has many employees.
The system has many skills.
An employee may have zero or more skills.
A skill belongs to zero or more employees.

If that's the case, you have the following tables:

```
Employee
----
ID (pk)
...

Skill
----
ID (pk)
Description 
...

Employee_skill
--------------
employee_id (fk)
skill_id (fk)
....
```

Comment: Yes that's my table structure at the moment, however I still receive the error of unique constraint.

Comment: _Yes that's my table structure at the moment_  Well, then we are shooting at a moving target as that is not what your question shows.  Unfortunately, the SO platform only allows structured, formatted code in either the original question or in Answers, making it difficult to modify a question without loosing context.  That said, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm not sure what ended up happening, once I restarted Oracle the next day my model seemed to work fine. Perhaps I was just doing something wrong, this was the end structure of my model: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68410677/16463270